# Deep customization of the comment form?

Tags: comments, comment-form

I've been handed over a design to translate into WordPress plugin & theme. My question is regarding building a custom comment form.

The design used some custom scripts on the comment submit button. It handles 'submitting...' button state, animations, and checks. And it uses an anchor tag `<a>` with jQuery's `.bind` to submit the form.

I noticed that the `comment_form` function of WordPress did not offer a solution to change the submit button. I only needed to remove it as I'm handling it myself.

What made it worse is that WordPress has hard coded `<input name="submit">` into the button, which made it impossible for jQuery to call `.submit` (more details on this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540953/property-submit-of-object-htmlformelement-is-not-a-function). So just hiding this button with CSS won't work.

If I prefer not to use the `<input type="submit">` button of WordPress comment form, do I have any options to build my own button?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit older question here, just thought a little update may help you
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/206349/33372

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hard. Output buffering could solve that:

```
add_action( 'comment_form_field_comment', 'ob_start' );
add_action( 'comment_form', 'wpse_83898_replace_submit' );

function wpse_83898_replace_submit() 
{
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    # do some magic
    echo $html;
}
```

Just an idea, not tested.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea. I ended up hooking `'comment_form_before'` and `'comment_form_after'` altogether. And I used `ob_start("hook_callback");` in 'before', and `ob_end_flush()` in 'after'. I then have a callback function to do whatever I want with the form.