# Change the tag of the comment submit button

Tags: comment-form

The `<input>` tags does not allow/support many CSS properties, so I want to change it to `<button>`.

How can I get that button and apply a filter to it?

Comment: Just curious, what CSS properties do you have in mind?

Comment: Generally pseudos like `:before` are not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to change the HTML structure for the comment form's submit, with the `comment_form_defaults` filter.

Here's an untested example:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', function( $defaults )
{
    // Edit this to your needs:
    $button = '<input name="%1$s" type="submit" id="%2$s" class="%3$s" value="%4$s" />';

    // Override the default submit button:
    $defaults['submit_button'] = $button;

    return $defaults;
} );
```

where you adjust the `$button` to your needs.

There's also the `comment_form_submit_button` filter:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_submit_button', function( $submit_button, $args )
{
    // Override the submit button HTML:
    $button = '<input name="%1$s" type="submit" id="%2$s" class="%3$s" value="%4$s" />';

    return sprintf(
        $button,
        esc_attr( $args['name_submit'] ),
        esc_attr( $args['id_submit'] ),
        esc_attr( $args['class_submit'] ),
        esc_attr( $args['label_submit'] )
     );

}, 10, 2 );
```

It should even be possible with the `comment_form_submit_field` filter, but it contains hidden fields as well, so it might not be as helpful as the other filters.

Comment: Thanks so much, the first method works, please update the second method `add_filter( 'comment_form_submit_button', function( $submit_button, $args ){}` I would like to use this one. The `$submit_button = '<input name="%1$s" type="submit" id="%2$s" class="%3$s" value="%4$s" />';` copied to the second method isn't working.

Comment: Great. I updated the example with the `comment_form_submit_button` filter. @thednp